# Assign a standard (web safe font) using @font-face for printing

Tags: css, fonts, media-queries

Currently, in my standard stylesheet I have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFancyFont;
    src: url('myFancyFont.otf');
}
```

And I use that in other css declarations like:

```
.someClass {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: myFancyFont;
}
```

That all works well and good until someone goes to print the page at which point anything using myFancyFont prints out in a rather ugly font.

---

- On screen version [image]
- Printed version [image]

---

Notice the font looks double lined and blurry.  My print.css file does change the background color from blue to grey.

Is it possible for me to redefine myFancyFont in my `print.css` file to a standard web safe font (like Verdana) so printing looks more normal?

I'm assuming that there could still be a problem if I simply do:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFancyFont;
    src: url('verdana.otf');  /*or a real version of the verdana font file*/
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding more filetypes for your custom font? Or add `media='print'` into your `<link rel='...'>` tag

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 Do you mean include the .ttf version (and others) of the font)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use an `@media print` media query with Verdana as the standard font, like this:

```
@media print {
  * {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
}
```

Plus, if you have other, more specific CSS rules where you define your FancyFont, you'd have to include these too in this media query (changed to Verdana), or use `!important` in the above rule.

Comment: Does this make the font Verdana for everything being printed and leave the screen fonts as is?

Comment: Yes, everything in that rule is only valid for printout and doesn't affect screen layout.

Comment: one correction here, typo mistake, font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;

Comment: @SreehariBallampalli yes of course, thanks for point that out – I edited my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for me to redefine myFancyFont in my `print.css` file to a standard web safe font (like Verdana) so printing looks more normal?

Yes, in your print stylesheet you can redefine your custom font family to use the preinstalled Verdana like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFancyFont;
    src: local('Verdana');
}
```

All references to myFancyFont in your standard stylesheet, provided they haven't been restricted to `@media screen`, will automatically use Verdana in print.

You do need to make sure that your print stylesheet is linked after your standard stylesheet in your HTML so that this `@font-face` rule will override your standard one.

Note that "web safe" doesn't necessarily mean "legible in paged media", although generally most web safe fonts *do* print pretty legibly.